# [OLE DB Source [963]] Error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I have created a Data Flow Task containing an OLEDB Source and an OLEDB destination.  The OLEDB source has a data access mode of: SQL Command From Variable.  The variable is called: SQLQuery.  The design time value of SQLQuery is:

```
select '' as PersonNo from Person
```

The SSIS package is throwing the following error:

```
[OLE DB Source [963]] Error: The "output column "PersonNo" (1051)" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "output column "Surname" (1051)" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
```

I do not understand this error.  However, if I do the following it seems to work:

select '1111111111' as PersonNo from Person

Can I specify the length of PersonNo in the SQL Query?

Comment: `SELECT CAST('' AS VARCHAR(10)) as PersonNo`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead use `NULL` like

```
SELECT NULL AS PersonNo FROM Person
```